# Prevent click on body until POST returns a response

Tags: reactjs, post, async-await, axios

On a React app, I would like to prevent click on the body until the POST method returns a response, and then allowing the user to click again on the body.

How would I do this? Here's what I tried to do:

```
    async post() {
    try {
        this.preventClick();
        await axios.post(`${url}`, data);
        this.authorizeClick();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

click = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

preventClick = (e) => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", this.click);
};

authorizeClick = (e) => {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", this.click);
};
```

Unfortunately this just prevents the click but does not allow click event after the POST method provides a response. Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `removeEventListener`, you have to pass it the function you want to remove.

You are passing it a *new* function (albeit an identical one), which isn't bound as an event listener, so it cannot be removed.

```
function preventClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function preventClick() {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", preventClickHandler);
}

function authorizeClick() {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", preventClickHandler);

}
```